# Other reasons for "no space left on device" than fully used folder?

Tags: disk-usage, tmp, qnx

I have a tests that I run on a device which has a `300M` of ram-disk based `/tmp` and I get `"no space left on device"` even though when I run `df -h` I find that only `11%` of the `/tmp` is actually used.

I am very confused, any hints on what should I look for?

Comment: What about `df -i` output?

Comment: just a shot in the dark. does it run MySQL?

Comment: Is it really _not enough space left_ as opposed to _no space left_? What application is it?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas it was a mistake, I added enough mistakenly. I have edited the question, thank you for pointing it out

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro No it is just some Networking code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two hypotheses come to mind:

- Running out of inodes (`df -i`)
- Disk quota for the user exceeded (`quota -u username`)

Answer (score 2):

It may well be that the test tries to create a file that's bigger than the available space, and it is deleted when hitting the "not enough space" condition. Try to monitor the disk space permanently on another console while running the test:

```
$ while true; do df -h /tmp; sleep 0.5; done
```